# Active directoryt Search for context CN=xxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com found no results

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, active-directory, ldap, wildfly

I'm using a local Active directory service Lightweight directory service that I created in a windows 7 machine. 
I created some users and roles and I configured wildfly 10 to use that instance to authenticate and authorize users, here is my conf :

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
<module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
<module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://localhost:389"/>
<module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
<module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=user1,CN=Users,CN=xxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
<module-option name="bindCredential" value="password"/>
<module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="CN=xxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
<module-option name="baseFilter" value="(cn={0})"/>
<module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=xxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com"/>
<module-option name="roleFilter" value="(cn={0})"/>
<module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="memberOf"/>
<module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="true"/>
<module-option name="roleNameAttributeID" value="cn"/>
<module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
<module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
<module-option name="allowEmptyPasswords" value="false"/>
```

when I authenticate a user over that AD instance I get :

> NamingException: PBOX00037: Search for context CN=xxx,DC=mydomain,DC=com found no results

however when I use an ldap client ( LDAP Administrator) I can connect to that Instance and I can filter using the same filter I get the expected result.

 can anyone help ?

Comment: I am guessing that your WildFly implementation is NOT following referrals. Trya dding something like:      <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>

Comment: I think that this option is the same as Context.REFERRAL, which I already use with the same suggested value. But anyway I'll try it.

Comment: try it , same result :(